# Cancellation theorem for direct and other kinds of products between groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

[Cancellation theorem](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2317133) in group theory (for direct product) says that if $B$ is a finite group and $A \times B \simeq A_1 \times B_1$ and $B \simeq B_1$ then $A \simeq A_1.$

Of course, if $B$ is not finite, the result is absurd, even for finitely presented groups ([Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=351637) is an example by Steve)

> I wonder whether the cancellation
>   theorem holds for different products
>   (in finite or infinite cases), such as
>   semi-direct product, free product,
>   fiber product over a given group,
>   Zappa-Szep product (knit product),
>   Wreath product.

Comment: Which of these various examples have you already tried?

Comment: There's an inherent lack of symmetry in other products, like the semidirect product or wreath product.  Which of the two subgroups involved would you like to cancel? I'm pretty sure there are counterexamples for either one though.

Comment: Also, from the Grushko decomposition theorem, it would seem that for free products, cancellation is possible for finitely presented groups.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: I tried for the semi-direct product of finite groups, but nothing came out!

Comment: @Steve D: That's a good point! I mean, for each sides of the semi-product, and wreath product (which I'm not very familiar and comfortable with the latter one)

Comment: Consider the maps of short exact sequences in the case of semidirect products...

Comment: Here's a counterexample for knit products: http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=2030472&messageID=6954692#6954692

Of course, knit products and semidirect products are more general than direct products, so the counterexample you cited above works in both those cases as well.

Comment: I think the question is a little bit to vague and unfocused.

Answer (score 3):

For a straightforward example that the subgroup doing the acting in a semidirect product cannot automatically be cancelled (and as semidirect products are knit products, also addresses that case), the dihedral group of order $8$ can be written as a semidirect product in two different ways: $C_4\rtimes C_2$ (with the action being inversion) and $(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$ (with the action being swap coordinates).

Comment: FWIW, the second of these is even a wreath product: $(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2 = C_2\wr C_2$, though I admit this doesn't compare a wreath product to a wreath product.